# Spring creating path to dispatcher servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there a way to create a path relative to the spring's dispatcher servlet path without using ServletUriComponentsBuilder? I read that you should use ServletUriComponentsBuilder to build paths but what if I don't have any request and I want to create path relative to the dispatcher servlet? In my case, I have a bean that connects to another server with web socket. When I get some messages from the other server, I want to be able to create some resources on the server and expose them by creating unique urls that target the running dispatcher servlet.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about `ServletUriConponentsBuilder`, honestly. For controller paths, you can use annotation `@RequestMapping`. Or I don't understanding your question correctly.

Comment: I think you did not understand what I need. I have a bean in my spring context and I want in this bean to create urls that point to spring's dispatcher servlet that is running. People use ServletUriConponentsBuilder but this seems to only work if you are doing this in a thread that manages/answers a request. In my case, I can't do this , because thread that needs to create url, does not answer/manage any request.